# grunt environment specific options for a task

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

In order to keep the gruntfile DRY I would like to change options based on the environment I'm running a grunt task for.

So for instance if I want to use two grunt tasks:

```
grunt.task.run('uglify:production');
grunt.task.run('uglify:development');
```

I would like them both to compile the same files, however with different options.

```
uglify: {

  production: {
    options: {
      compress: true
    }
  }

  development: {
    options: {
      compress: false,
      beautify: true
    }
  }

  // rather not redeclare these files twice
  files: {

    vendor: {
      // this name should change based on the environment
      'dest/vendor-output.js': ['src/vendor-input1.js', 'src/vendor-input2.js']
    },
    custom: {
      'dest/custom-output.js': ['src/custominput1.js', 'src/custominput2.js']
    }

 }
```

If production could even have the destination name to custom-output.min.js that would be even more ideal.

Tried an if-else statement but inside the grunt task definition that doesn't fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the grunt config is just json you could use grunt templates and have your files as a property of the config.

```
uglifyFiles: {

  vendor: {
    // this name should change based on the environment
    'dest/vendor-output.js': ['src/vendor-input1.js', 'src/vendor-input2.js']
  },
  custom: {
    'dest/custom-output.js': ['src/custominput1.js', 'src/custominput2.js']
  }
},
uglify: {

  production: {
    options: {
      compress: true
    },
    files: '<%= uglifyFiles %>'
  },

  development: {
    options: {
      compress: false,
      beautify: true
    },
    files: '<%= uglifyFiles %>'
  }
}
```

http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#templates

Sorry i didn't quite understand this question

> If production could even have the destination name to
>   custom-output.min.js that would be even more ideal.

Could you give a little more info, or is the above what you where trying to achieve?

**EDIT**

Seems like what you're trying to do takes the repeat part out of DRY as you actually want slightly different code in each. It could be done but not in the json, you'd need to use js and use bracket notation to create the destination as its a key. I think a much simpler way, and what grunt is set up like this for, would be to do the following.

```
vendorUglifyFiles: ['src/vendor-input1.js', 'src/vendor-input2.js'],
customUglifyFiles: ['src/custominput1.js', 'src/custominput2.js'],
uglify: {

  production: {
    options: {
      compress: true
    },
    files: {
      vendor: {
        'dest/vendor.min.js': '<%= vendorUglifyFiles %>'
      },
      custom: {
        'dest/custom.min.js': '<%= customUglifyFiles %>'
      }
    }
  },

  development: {
    options: {
      compress: false,
      beautify: true
    },
    files: {
      vendor: {
        'dest/vendor.js': '<%= vendorUglifyFiles %>'
      },
      custom: {
        'dest/custom.js': '<%= customUglifyFiles %>'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Edit: 11-08-2016, 15:12**

Removed the level that throws the indexOf error:

```
vendorUglifyFiles: ['src/vendor-input1.js', 'src/vendor-input2.js'],
customUglifyFiles: ['src/custominput1.js', 'src/custominput2.js'],
uglify: {

  production: {
    options: {
      compress: true
    },
    files: {
      'dest/vendor.min.js': '<%= vendorUglifyFiles %>',
      'dest/custom.min.js': '<%= customUglifyFiles %>'
    }
  },

  development: {
    options: {
      compress: false,
      beautify: true
    },
    files: {
        'dest/vendor.js': '<%= vendorUglifyFiles %>',
        'dest/custom.js': '<%= customUglifyFiles %>'
    }
  }
}
```

That does the trick.

Comment: I'm trying to get a task to compile into either a minified production version or a normal beautified development version of the files. The example you wrote works for the first part. Now only the file names should be either vendor.js for development or vender.min.js for the production version.

Comment: It seems that nesting `vendor` and `custom` underneath the `production` task throws a `Warning: pattern.indexOf is not a function` error. Removing that extra level does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Grunt is Javascript, so you can actually add IF/ELSE statements.

Example:

```
files: {
    (() => { 
        if (grunt.option('vendor')) {
            return {
                'dest/vendor-output.js': ['src/vendor-input1.js', 'src/vendor-input2.js']
            }
        } else (grunt.option('release')) {
            return {
                'dest/custom-output.js': ['src/custominput1.js', 'src/custominput2.js']
            }
        }
    }())
}

/***
 * OR SOMETHING LIKE
 **/

files: {
    (() => { 
        switch(grunt.option) {
            case 'vendor':
                return {
                    'dest/vendor-output.js': ['src/vendor-input1.js', 'src/vendor-input2.js']
                };
                break;
            case 'release:
                return {
                    'dest/custom-output.js': ['src/custominput1.js', 'src/custominput2.js']
                };
                break;
            default:
                return {};
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously, you need to change this to your desired situation because it is now unknow how you address vendor and/or release.

Comment: Shouldn't the production and development options be caught in this conditional, based on the grunt task `uglify:production` or `uglify:development`?

Comment: That is possible too. You can also set a variable like: `grunt uglify --type=production` and collect it with: `grunt.option('type') // = production`